# Machine learning: Is it possible to use k-means to filter out wrong-orientation pictures?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

Say I have a set of pictures, some of them are of wrong-orientation, i.e. ones have to be rotated 90 degrees left/right for viewing. Is this problem suitable of using k-means? If this is possible, which metrics would be good? If not, what are some better alternatives?

Comment: May I know what kinds of the images you have?

Comment: @LeeHoYo: Profile pictures.

Comment: I think you have to normalize the images, before running any learning algorithm, like brightness, contrast, and rotation etc.

Comment: @LeeHoYo: I agree with that, but what I want to do is make those wrong-orientation pics into one group...

Comment: Aha, you can keep the orientation and only process brightness, contrast. Intuitively, it is working.